# Script field to retrieve part of a string field

Tags: elasticsearch

How Can I use script field to retrieve the first 20 words around the search word for a string field ?

Suppose I have a field called Conent which is very lengthy . So If I am seraching sor "apple" in Content I should get atmost 20 words aroung the word apple .

How can I achieve this ?
Is fragment_size will do the trick ??

Comment: Yeah, that's what highlighters are for, except they allow to specify fragment size in characters not in words. Did you try to use them?

Comment: Yes I tried but din't get result as I expected .I stt fragment_size=100 and when I search for 'official' in my content field I got "11 13 11 13 11 13 25 " in fragment array .Any idea ???

Comment: My query is https://gist.github.com/4124453  and I got https://gist.github.com/4124450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it highlights numbers from your range query. Try replacing the boolean query in the first "must" clause with this:

```
"filtered": {
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "official",
            "default_field": "Content"
        }
    }, 
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "actualTimeStamp": {
                "from": "08-04-2011 23:37:06",
                "to": "16-11-2012 00:00:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```